# source cshrc file in python

Tags: python, environment, csh

I have to source a cshrc file from python and store the environment variables set by the cshrc file only in a dictionary. I am using this:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
    f'''source {file}; python -c "import os, json; 
print(json.dumps(dict(os.environ)))"''',
    shell=True, executable='/bin/csh')
env = json.loads(output)
```

However, this also prints these variables:

```
{'VENDOR': 'unknown', 'SHLVL': '1', 'PWD': <>, 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64-linux', 'HOST': <>, 
'LOGNAME': <>, 'USER': <>, 'OSTYPE': 'linux', 'GROUP': 'users', 'MACHTYPE': 'x86_64', 
variables_from_file}
```

How do I ensure only those variables are returned that are there from the file? I cannot filter out the above variables cause what if they are actually there in the file. I tried cleaning up environment before calling the subprocess but that also didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash`?

Comment: Cause I want to source a cshrc file via python. I could use bash script but I have to do it via python.

Comment: You can try passing an empty environment (i.e. `env={}` in the subprocess call), which should prevent including the environment from your running program, but it may still include things set in the cshrc file(s). You can get around it by setting a fake HOME environment, maybe. There isn't really a flag to disable that, or to disable loading the system-wide configs.

Comment: It would be easiest to modify the script to echo what you want, if possible. Or if the file is simple enough (e.g. just some `setenv`s), it may be easier to parse the file with a simple Python script. Or you can run `csh` twice: one to print the environment with `env`, and the second one with your `source` command and then get the difference between the two.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand. How do I set up a fake HOME environment? I didn't understand, print the environment with env. The cshrc file has setenvs and it also has sourcing of other cshrc files.

Comment: I think this has done the trick:



output = subprocess.check_output(
    f'''unsetenv VENDOR ; unsetenv GROUP ; source {file}; python -c "import os, json; 
print(json.dumps(dict(os.environ)))"''',
    shell=True, executable='/bin/csh')
env = json.loads(output)